# How to achieve progressive disclosure of facet fields in Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, faceted-search

A good example is amazon.com, where a search for "ipod" would bring a results page with only 2 facets ("Departments" and "Shipping option").

When I hit "Electronics" on the "Departments" facet, the results page reveal new facets like "Brand", "Condition", and others.

I keep finding new facets while drilling down the same "Departments" hierarchical facet, for example at "Any Department / Electronics / Portable Audio & Video / MP3 Players & Accessories / MP3 Players", there is "Capacity", "Player feature", "Supported Standard", and many others.

I´ve been searching A LOT about how to implement this architecture, so any pointers or keywords would be of great help.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Just to clarify, the question is about the selective display of facets, based on previous facet choices. The issue of hierarchical faceting is ok and enough documented.

Comment: I did not understand the Question, if it is not about hierarchical faceting, Can you please elobrate.

Comment: Sorry, I found it really hard to frame it simply.
The question is how do I enable new facets based on previous facet choices (eg how do I show the "Capacity" facet only after the user choses "Mp3 players" on "Department" facet) ?